# How can I query for consecutive values above a specific count in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table:

```
id  dummy_data
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   b
5   b
6   c
7   b
8   c
9   c
10  c
```

I need to query for all *consecutive* `dummy_data` values above a count of a certain threshold, let's say 2, such that the result is thus:

```
+----+------------+
| id | dummy_data |
+----+------------+
|  1 | a          |
|  2 | c          |
+----+------------+
```

I have written this query:

```
select 
  t1.dummy_data
from 
  data_table t1
    join data_table t2 on t1.id = t2.id + 1
    join data_table t3 on t1.id = t3.id + 2
where
    t1.dummy_data + ' ' + t2.dummy_data + ' ' + t3.dummy_data = 
    t1.dummy_data + ' ' + t1.dummy_data + ' ' + t1.dummy_data
```

...which gets me:

```
+------------+
| dummy_data |
+------------+
| a          |
| c          |
+------------+
```

My understanding is that this is a variant of a type of problem called "gaps and islands."

However, I have two problems:
1.) What I've done is obviously not scalable, and
2.) I am simply failing to understand how I can reset the ID primary keys so that they reset in the query results.

How can I accomplish this? Found here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/33b27/7

... but schema creation below just in case:

```
create table data_table (
    id int primary key,
    dummy_data varchar(10)
);

insert into data_table (id, dummy_data) values
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'a'),
    (3, 'a'),
    (4, 'b'),
    (5, 'b'),
    (6, 'c'),
    (7, 'b'),
    (8, 'c'),
    (9, 'c'),
    (10, 'c');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting your own solution but then using `lag` instead of joins:

```
WITH SUB AS 
  (SELECT id, 
   dummy_data, 
   lag(dummy_data, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as dd1, 
   lag(dummy_data, 2) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as dd2
  FROM data_table)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS id, dummy_data 
FROM SUB
WHERE dummy_data = dd1 AND dd1 = dd2
```

Answer (score 1):

This will accommodate an arbitrary number of consecutive matches.

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (order by id) as rn,
        row_number() over (partition by dummy_data order by id) as rn2
    from T
)
select row_number() over (order by rn - rn2), min(dummy_data)
from data
group by rn - rn2
having count(*) >= X;
```

Comment: Thank you. I receive the error "Column 'data.dummy_data' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." What does this mean?

Comment: It needed to be aggregated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` or `lead()`.  For three in a row:

```
select min(id), dummy_data
from (select t.*,
             lag(id, 2) over (order by id) as prev_id,
             lag(id, 2) over (partition by dummy_data order by id) as prev_id_dd
      from t
     ) t
where prev_id = prev_id_dd
group by dummy_data;
```

The logic is simple.  Peak back *n - 1* rows.  Then, peak back *n - 1* rows that have the same `dummy_data` value.  If these are the same, then all intervening rows have the same value.

Comment: Thank you, I'm confused by the `t` variable in the `from` syntax, is that meant to stand for table? Can you tell me why it is needed?

Comment: @saktas001 . . . That is the table name which is not specified in the question.  Note:  This is more general than the solution you have currently accepted.  It is quite simple to extend this to any value of `n`.